# Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface IndexTableRowSizeEstimatorInterface

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.2

I am upgrading our magento 2.1.9 to magento 2.2.7.
When reindexing catalog_category_product, it throw this error:

```
[23-Jan-2019 09:49:39 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexTableRowSizeEstimatorInterface in /home/don/Web/fabelio22/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111
Stack trace:
#0 /home/don/Web/fabelio22/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#1 /home/don/Web/fabelio22/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#2 /home/don/Web/fabelio22/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#3 /home/don/Web/fabelio22/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#4 /home/don/Web/fabelio22/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Category/Product/Action/Full.ph in /home/don/Web/fabelio22/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111
```

The di.xml in Magento_Catalog is

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full">
   <arguments>
      <argument name="batchRowsCount" xsi:type="number">100000</argument>
      <argument name="batchSizeManagement" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\CategoryProductBatchSize</argument>
   </arguments>
</type>
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\CategoryProductBatchSize" type="Magento\Framework\Indexer\BatchSizeManagement">
   <arguments>
      <argument name="rowSizeEstimator" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\RowSizeEstimator</argument>
   </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

But $rowSizeEstimator is not injected with the correct class.It tries to instantiate \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexTableRowSizeEstimatorInterface instead. generated/metadata/global.php is generated, but it's like Magento  ignore the compiled di file.

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing the cache and generation directories.

1. Clear `var/generation`
2. Clear `var/cache`
3. Run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

**Note:** If you use redis for caching then you should also consider clearing redis cache.

Comment: i did and it doesn't help

Comment: nope. we postponed this upgrade until we have free time.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue i.e. cannot instantiate interface for some third party module.
The reason that I found out after debugging that the corresponding module's entry was missing from the app/etc/config.xml but the module's code was present in the codebase. 
After manually adding the module's entry in the app/etc/config.xml file, the issue got resolved.